# Convert Date::Manip::Obj to Time::Piece or Class::Date

Tags: perl, date, time, type-conversion

I want to do comparisons between dates and they need to be correct even after a daylight savings time change (e.g. CEST to CET). The problem is that I can't get this working with [`Date::Manip::Obj`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Manip::Obj).

In the documentation, they speak of it being possible with [`Time::Piece`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) and I also tested that.

The problem is that I can't convert a [`Date::Manip`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Manip) parsed object into a `Time::Piece` object. How can I do this? I have a `Date::Manip` object because I need to use this library to parse a date in an OpenSSL Packet.

If somebody knows how to correctly use `Date::Manip` in a way that it works with Daylight Changing times, let me know.

This is some code to test the comparison. The LastUpdate variable is just a date in the past so I can compare this to now, when going from CEST to CET.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin;

use Date::Manip::Date;
use Date::Manip::Delta;
use Date::Manip::TZ;
use Data::Dumper;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

# To simulate checking a recently-published CRL against the current time, set a lastUpdate time
# to now() - 1 minute (for instance). Then, using the OS date --set command, set the system date
# to a few seconds before the DST rollover from CEST to CET (happens at 03:00:00 on the last sunday
# of october -- 27 Oct in 2013), and then run the script.

my $date = new Date::Manip::Date "now";
my $delta = $date->new_delta();
my $tz = new Date::Manip::TZ;

$delta->parse("-00:01:00");

my $dmLastUpdate = $date->calc($delta);
my $tpLastUpdate = Time::Piece->new;
$tpLastUpdate -= ONE_MINUTE;

my $now = $date->new_date();
while (1)
{
    $now->parse("now");
    my $dmTz = $tz->curr_zone();
    my $dmNowLarger = $now->cmp($dmLastUpdate);

    my $tpNow = Time::Piece->new;
    my $tpTz = $tpNow->strftime("\%Z (\%z)");

    printf "\%-30s: \%s\n", "DateManip \$tz", (defined($dmTz) ? $dmTz : "");
    printf "\%-30s: \%s\n", "DateManip now ", $date->printf("%C");
    printf "\%-30s: \%s\n", "DateManip lastUpdate ", $dmLastUpdate->printf("%C");
    printf "\%-30s: \%s\n", "DateManip now > lastUpdate ", $dmNowLarger;
    printf "\%-30s: \%s\n", "TimePiece \$tz ", $tpTz;
    printf "\%-30s: \%s\n", "TimePiece now ", $tpNow->strftime();
    printf "\%-30s: \%s\n", "TimePiece lastUpdate ", $tpLastUpdate->strftime();
    printf "\%-30s: \%s\n", "TimePiece now > lastUpdate ", ($tpNow > $tpLastUpdate);
    printf "-------------------------------------------------------\n";
    sleep (3);
}
```

The moment the daylight saving time changes from summer to winter ( 3am cest to 2am cet) it cmp() returns -1 and this should be 1 because it is actually later if you look at the time zones.

With Time:Piece, that comparison works well so that is why I want to convert the date::manip to Time:piece

Comment: Why not just abandon your use of Date::Manip? It hasn't been recommended for years. You can parse your dates directly into Time::Piece objects using the `strptime` method.

Comment: I am trying that now. But if I add a specific timezone like GMT and I print the epoch, the epoch is not in the GMT timezone but in my system time zone.

Comment: I don't understand what that means. An epoch value isn't in any timezone. It's just a number. It's the same whatever timezone you're in.

Comment: Are you trying to do calculations for your time zone, or for another TZ? Time::Piece seems to be localized to the time zone you are in--both if parsing a date using `strptime` and using the `new` constructor, it sets the time zone to whatever your system is set to. You might be better off using something like DateTime instead.

Comment: I am trying to calculate for a TZ which the openSSL packet I received contains. So I need to specify the TZ that is in that packet and then calculate with my own system time and TZ if the certificate has not expired. Now I parsed the expiry date out of the openSSL packet with Date::Manip. Do you know another module in CPAN or elsewhere that can handle different TZ's? So I need to compare that date with the date and time of now on the server, with the different Timezones. The one from the packet and the one from the local server.

Comment: [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) is what I have always used for anything related to date or time. It can accept dates/times in different formats and you can use it to do calculations, so it should work well for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize a `Time::Piece` object by passing epoch seconds as an argument to `new`:

```
my $tp = Time::Piece->new( 123456789 );
say $tp->strftime();
say $tp->epoch();
## output: 
## Thu, 29 Nov 1973 21:33:09 BST
## 123456789
```

To get the epoch time out of `Date::Manip::Date`, you can do the following:

```
$date->printf('%s');
```

You can also parse a time using `Time::Piece->strptime`:

```
my $tp2 = Time::Piece->strptime("1:24:08 PM 1996-02-03", "%H:%M:%S %p %Y-%m-%d" );
```

Note that it does not appear possible to set Time::Piece to use a particular time zone; it takes the system time zone if using `new` (which calls the underlying system strptime function), and UTC if using `strptime`. If you are working with a specific time zone, you may need to either set your system to the time zone you're working with, or use a different module.